# Help with IF has focus then... statment

Tags: functions, jquery

in a sidebar I have:

```
<div id="my_id"> [shortcode]</div>
```

It outputs a title that when hovered on drops down to show a menu.

When hovering on the title a background color shows up and disappears when the mouse moves down to the menu items.

I need for the background color to remain as long as the menu has focus, I need something like:

```
If #my_id has focus then .my_link {background:red;}
```

I have looked and the only thing that looked promising was (not really sure how to use this)

JQuery:js_focus

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

   $('input').blur(function(){
            $('input').removeClass("focus");
      })
         .focus(function() {                
             $(this).addClass("focus")
      });

});
```

CSS:

```
.focus {
    background:red;
    }
```

In functions.php:

```
function load_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('my_javascript_file', 'http://example.com/wp-content/themes/Child-Theme/js_focus.js', array('jquery'));
}    
add_action('init', 'load_scripts');
```

Then in style.css:

```
.focus .my_link {background:red;}
```

Is this a good approach?, if so (not working at the moment) I only want focus on the menu to give the background color.

If not a good approach any other ideas all are welcomed and appreciated

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Did you `wp_register_script` first? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script, and don't use the `init` hook, use `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `admin_enqueue_scripts` hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery is not correct (syntax and logic), this isn't really a WordPress question. To toggle focus effects you can do something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608181/jquery-toggle-focus